# call second function once the first function execution is completed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 `functions`, `say A() and B().` I want to call `function B()` after the `function A()` execution is completed.
and I dont want to write the the `function B()` calling inside the definition of `function A()`, because `function A()` is used in other modules too and that take unnecessary.
I am trying to call function A() first and then once it is done then call `function B()`. because `function B()` uses `function A() $scope variable`

I use `.then()` but its giving error `.then() undefined` something.
I called `function B()` inside function A() that works but i don't want that way.

```
$scope.fetchApplicantData();  //function A()
$scope.fetchMobileMessages($scope.ApplicantMicroDetails.AD_I_PASTEMP_RESI_CONTACT_NO);    //function B()
```

I am expecting to call `function A()` first once it is done call the `function B()`. because `function B()` uses `function A()` variable, but is don't want to call `function b()` inside the definition in `function A()`

Comment: possibke dupliacte of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: If the functions are asynchronous, they need to be coded so that they return promises. The `.then() undefined` message means that the functions are not returning promises and are not properly coded in a way that can be chained. To help you fix the functions we need to see the code for those functions.

Comment: ok thanks, let me fix this function first and try

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) like this:

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve('foo');
  }, 300);
});

promise1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  // expected output: "foo"
});

console.log(promise1);
```